# Access iOS microphone without muting audio?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

If a user runs Spotify or another audio app in the background while playing my game, the audio is fine until I access the microphone, at which point audio gets muted.

The release notes for AIR 15.0.0.27 state that one of the fixed issues is:

- [iOS8] Requesting microphone access terminates all further audio.

However, I'm experiencing this with AIR 15.0.0.356.

Can this be avoided? And if not, what do I do to restore audio again after the user is done using the microphone?